# CraftCMS - CraftQL querying globals always returns error

Tags: javascript, php, yii, graphql, craftcms

When querying globals from the GraphiQl interface, from my frontend application, or from an API explorer like Insomnia, CraftQL returns an error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

I am running Craft 3.1.8 and CraftQL 1.3.1.

```
query getGlobalTest {
  globals {
    ... on GlobalsSet {
      test {
        ... on Test {
          test
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error occurs in `vendor/markhuot/craftql/src/Types/Query.php` on line 215.

```php
foreach ($setIds as $id) {
  $set = \Craft::$app->globals->getSetById($id, $siteId);
  $sets[$set->handle] = $set;  <-- Error line
}
```

This happens when querying anything in globals. I read somewhere that this has to do with Craft updating to UUIDs in Craft 3.1, however, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

That error just means your getSetById() query returned nothing. You wouldn't pass a UUID to that either. It expects an int. Are you sure your $siteId variable is correct? If you want to avoid errors, you could add this to your code:

```
foreach ($setIds as $id) {
    if ($set = \Craft::$app->globals->getSetById($id, $siteId)) {
        $sets[$set->handle] = $set;
    }
}
```

But I would suggest taking a look a the $siteId, or removing it altogether.

Comment: Well, that does seem to fix it.  I am not sure how to pass this on to the developer or putting in a PR since I don't know what effect this will have on other users.

Comment: You can pass it on to the dev by adding an issue here: https://github.com/markhuot/craftql/issues